# Table of Content Web Part SP2010

Tags: 2010, web-part

I'm currently designing a site in 2010 version for our team. They are not very comfortable using SharePoint and since migrated to version 2010 they are struggling with the basic navigation, so I would like to insert a *[table of content web part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-the-table-of-contents-web-part-to-display-navigation-on-a-web-page-HA101794728.aspx#BMuse_toc)* to ease the navigation.

As far as I understand the ***Table of Content Web Part*** is in the **Content Rollup** category but I cannot find it. Am I looking at the right section? Do I need specific set up prior to the addition of this web part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Content Rollup type web parts are part of SharePoint Server Enterprise.  Can you confirm that you have an Enterprise license and that the enterprise features (including Publishing) are deployed on the site?

Comment: And that the publishing infrastructure is activated.

Comment: I can confirm that my company has SharePoint Server Enterprise license but there are different levels of access throughout the organization. How can I confirm the features I got access to?

Comment: If you are a site collection admin then go to the root of the site collection you are working with and click Site Actions, Site Settings, and then select the Site collection features link.  The Enterprise and Publishing features can be activated from there if available.

Comment: That was perfect! Activated the Publishing feature at the Site Collection Settings and worked as you said. Thank you for your help :)